# android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I have a problem in my NavigationDrawer layout with error:

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

This is my onCreateView:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);
        mRecyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
        mAdapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), new NavigationDrawerAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int index) {
                selectItem(index);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final int index) {
                Pins.Item item = mAdapter.getItem(index);
                Utils.showConfirmDialog(getActivity(), R.string.remove_shortcut,
                        R.string.confirm_remove_shortcut, item.getDisplay(getActivity()), new CustomDialog.SimpleClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPositive(int which, View view) {
                                Pins.remove(getActivity(), index);
                                mAdapter.reload(getActivity());
                            }
                        }
                );
                return false;
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter.setCheckedPos(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return mRecyclerView;
    }
```

And this is the `fragment_drawer` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/banner" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cover_bg"
        android:background="?drawer_background"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how it can't cast the RelativeLayout.. Same crash with LinearLayout.

Comment: You are casting your layout (a RelativeLayout) to a RecycleView at `mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false); you can't do` which you can't do

Comment: Yes but how can i do? I need put an image over my recycleview. if i put the image in my item_drawer.xml (that is the same layout in which i put the TextView items of the recycleview), it shows me the image not one time but for each item of the adapter. So i have (Banner - textview, Banner - textview, Banner - textview) and not (Banner, textview,textview,textview) Understand what i mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);
```

Your `fragment_drawer` layout does not have a `RecyclerView` as its root element. It has a `RelativeLayout` as its root element. Hence, `inflate()` will be returning the `RelativeLayout`, which itself has the `RecyclerView` inside of it.

Change your code to:

```
View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Here, we get the `RecyclerView` by finding the `@android:id/list` widget inside the inflated layout.